# Is this dependency upgrade in Ubuntu safe?

Tags: ubuntu, php, ubuntu-12.04

I am wanting to install PHP5 on an internal production server running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I try to use `apt-get` to install it lists a multitude of dependencies and recommends running `apt-get -f install`. When I run that I get this returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-59 linux-headers-3.2.0-59-generic linux-headers-server linux-image-3.2.0-59-generic linux-image-server linux-server
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-3.2.0 linux-source-3.2.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-59 linux-headers-3.2.0-59-generic linux-image-3.2.0-59-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
3 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 379 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 51.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 218 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? n
```

Is this a safe upgrade to do on a production machine? I know `apt-get dist-upgrade` can be pretty major and break things. Is this a minor upgrade or major?

Thanks

---Update 1---

The `/boot` partition is full, not allowing me to run `apt-get -f install`. When attempting to run this script from ubuntugenius `dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge` I get the following:

```
rgs sudo apt-get -y purge 
[sudo] password for tech: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-server : Depends: linux-headers-3.2.0-59-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.37.44) but 3.2.0.59.70 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I feel like im stuck in a bit of a loop now with a full `/boot` that wont let me run repairs, yet I cant purge `/boot` without running the repairs.

--- Update 2 ----

I have successfully cleared out some space in `/boot` only now to get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 379 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,732 B of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.37.44); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.59.70.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.37.44); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.59.70.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get -f install` is a *repair* operation. So something is *currently* wrong with your system that this is intended to fix.

My guess would be, if you haven't got a kernel installed now, that you *really* need to do this, as your system right now might not even be bootable!

Comment: Thanks. Apparently my boot partition is full so I am currently looking into purging old before being able to run this repair. I'm reading up on this method http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/

Comment: Yes, a full `/boot` is almost certainly why it would have failed previously.

Comment: Please see update 1 above. I cant even get things to purge from `/boot`

Comment: You shouldn't be doing anything else with `apt-get` until you have successfully run `apt-get -f install`. You'll have to clean out `/boot` manually.

Comment: Whats the best method for cleaning out `/boot` manually?

Comment: I would use the `rm` command.

Comment: thanks. Ill check for some guides so I dont muck too much up

Comment: update 2 added above. more errors after cleaning up space

Answer (score 1):

It's just a kernel upgrade which is available. You can update without problems. Once you reboot it will load the new kernel. If something does happen, you can choose the older kernel at your bootloader and uninstall the latest one.